# 3d Convolution vs CNN-LSTM for Gesture recognition

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm, computer-vision

I want to implement a gesture recognition system from video (of hand movements).

Some people have experimented with 3d convolutions to extract not only spatial features out of images, but also extract temporal features.

My question is, how does this architecture compare with a CNN on a per frame basis, to an LSTM network ?
Is there an obvious reason to choose one over the other ?

Comment: http://blog.qure.ai/notes/deep-learning-for-videos-action-recognition-review.
Not really the answer you want but a good read that sheds some light.