# Comparing 3d convolution and recurrent 2d convolution in anisotropic volumetric imagery

Tags: conv-neural-network, lstm

**My question is related to this (unanswered) [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266902/3d-convolution-vs-cnn-lstm-for-gesture-recognition), but with an emphasis on the anisotropy of the problem.**

I'm currently working on a project predicting the $k$-th slice of some volume of imagery given the previous $k-1$ slices. Let's say that the anisotropy of the imagery is such that the z dimension has a resolution roughly ten times more granular than the x and y dimensions, something like $20$ x $2$ x $2$ nanometers.

In considering the semantics of two different approaches for solving this problem, 3d convolution and recurrent 2d convolution, my intuition is that while 3d convolution might be more useful for analysis of isotropic image volumes, a recurrent structure might be more effective for significantly anisotropic imagery.

I haven't been able to find any literature specifically comparing these two techniques. If anyone has any thoughts on this or can point me in the direction of any discussion of the pros and cons of these techniques, I'd love to hear!